Celery name task execution and get task execution by name
I have a Celery task called my_task. I create multiple exeucutions of the task by calling my_task.delay() multiple times. I want to give a unique label/name to each execution, and to be able to get and stop a task execution for a given label/name. How can I do something like this?

Tasks are assigned an ID when created. To revoke a task, you can just use the revoke method on the task object itself or you can call app.control.revoke with the ID of the task.
task = my_task.delay()
print(task.id)  # a string identifier like abc1234-5678-4bec-b71a-665ba5d23004
# cancel _this_ task
task.revoke()
# or
app.control.revoke(task.id)

If you really want to refer to these by a plain name, you can store a mapping of names to IDs...
tasks = {} # a mapping to store names to tasks (or task IDs)
task = my_task.delay()
name = 'foo'
tasks[name] = task.id
# then later, decide you want to cancel task 'foo'
...
foo_task_id = tasks['foo']
app.control.revoke(foo_task_id)

This assumes you are using a broker that supports revocation of tasks.
